# ¿Cómo seleccionar N puntos dentro de un perimetro segun campo de tipo SqlGeography?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Nesecito construir una consulta donde pase como parámetro un punto por ejemplo:

geography::Point( 10.623771,-71.659139, 4326)  y me devuelva todo los registros que esten cerca de esta localización.

Escribí esta consulta pero solo me devuelve si el punto es igual:

```
select restaurantid ,Position.ToString() from deliveryconfiguration WHERE A.Position.ToString() = geography::Point(-74.0049539 ,40.6502672, 4326).ToString()
```

Comment: Me parece que debes consultar por un polígono y no por el punto exacto, ya que de otra forma no tendrías como delimitar el rango de alcance. Revisa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054149/sql-server-2008-spatial-find-a-point-in-polygon

Comment: sería interesante que comentes lo que estás haciendo, es decir, lo que andas programando

Comment: fredyxfx , Nesecito seleccionar los registros de farmacias que esten cerca de un punto dado ....

Comment: Maetschl ,  soy nuevo en esto y lo unico que tengo es Point( 10.623771,-71.659139, 4326) para hacer la busqueda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los puntos más cercanos son aquellos cuya distancia es menor.

En el ejemplo que he preparado, creo *al vuelo* una *tabla* que contiene datos de sucursales, incluyendo su latitud y longitud, luego calculo el punto de geometría correspondiente a dicha latitud/longitud y finalmente obtengo las 3 sucursales más cercanas a un punto dado.

Las latitudes y longitudes utilizadas son puntos reales, ubicados en la ciudad de Guatemala, por lo que fácilmente puedes comprobar los resultados, por ejemplo, con google maps o google earth.

```
with 
Sucursal as (
          select 14.6057619 Latitud, -90.5116068 Longitud, '1a. Avenida Z. 10' Descripcion
union all select 14.6023254, -90.5206083, 'Plazuela España Z. 9'
union all select 14.5947254, -90.5150078, 'C. C. Los Proceres Z. 10'
union all select 14.5985885, -90.5067823, 'Oakland Mall Z. 10'
union all select 14.5876183, -90.5037719, '20 Calle Z. 10'
)
,
UbicacionSucursal as (
select *, geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + cast(longitud as varchar) + ' ' + cast(latitud as varchar) + ')', 4326) Ubicacion
  from Sucursal
)
select   top 3 
         us.Latitud
       , us.Longitud
       , us.Descripcion
       , geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-90.504263 14.5895462)', 4326).STDistance(us.Ubicacion) Distancia
  from UbicacionSucursal us
 order by geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(14.5895462 -90.504263)', 4326).STDistance(us.Ubicacion)
```

**[Edit]**

En los comentarios a esta pregunta el OP ha especificado que busca encontrar los puntos que se encuentran dentro de un radio de X metros del punto de referencia, en ese caso voy a cambiar la referencia de geometry a geography, para obtener las distancias en metros, y filtrar con un where los que están dentro del radio buscado:

```
with 
Sucursal as (
          select 14.6057619 Latitud, -90.5116068 Longitud, '1a. Avenida Z. 10' Descripcion
union all select 14.6023254, -90.5206083, 'Plazuela España Z. 9'
union all select 14.5947254, -90.5150078, 'C. C. Los Proceres Z. 10'
union all select 14.5985885, -90.5067823, 'Oakland Mall Z. 10'
union all select 14.5876183, -90.5037719, '20 Calle Z. 10'
)
,
UbicacionSucursal as (
select *, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + cast(longitud as varchar) + ' ' + cast(latitud as varchar) + ')', 4326) Ubicacion
  from Sucursal
)
select   us.Latitud
       , us.Longitud
       , us.Descripcion
       , geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-90.504263 14.5895462)', 4326).STDistance(us.Ubicacion) Distancia
  from UbicacionSucursal us
 where geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-90.504263 14.5895462)', 4326).STDistance(us.Ubicacion) < 2000 --2Km
```

Comment: jachguate gracias...Algo que no me queda claro es por que tu SELECT no tienen una clausula WHERE, por eso te pido que me aclares ese punto por favor

Comment: No tiene where, porque en mi interpretación de tu planteamiento, que es obtener las **n sucursales más cercanas a un punto**, no es necesario el where. Sería diferente, si quisieras obtener, por ejemplo, las sucursales que queden en el radio de X metros (o Kilómetros) de un punto, en ese caso, si que sería necesario poner un where, sin importar cuántos resultados obtengas. Como repito, esa es mi interpretación de tu planteamiento, pero si lo he interpretado mal, no quedaría mal si aclaras exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: La verdad soy nuevo con este tipo de Datos... Y lo que busco es obtener los registro en un radio de 2 km a la redonda ...por que luego tengo que marcarlos en un mapa de google ..Disculpa mi error ...

Comment: Y nesecito completar esta consulta (No funciona) ...con lo q tu sabes  SELECT ISNULL(AVG (B.FoodQuality),0) AS FoodQuality , ISNULL(AVG (B.Price),0) AS Price , ISNULL(AVG (B.Punctuality),0) AS Punctuality , ISNULL(AVG (B.Courtesy),0) AS Courtesy FROM DeliveryConfiguration A , RestaurantReview B
WHERE A.Position.STDistance(@position) IS NOT NULL  AND Position.STDistance(@position) <= 2000 ;

Comment: @Efrain, te sugiero editar la pregunta para reflejar que buscas los N puntos dentro de un radio. He editado la respuesta para incluir un ejemplo que te da todas las sucursales dentro de un radio de 2 Km. de un punto dado.